# cmd pops up at startup with "unable to open xmrig.json"

Tags: windows, powershell, malware

Whenever I start my PC It starts cmd that says :

unable to open "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Dll\config.json".

unable to open "C:\Users\username.xmrig.json".

unable to open "C:\Users\username.config\xmrig.json".

Now I came to know that 'xmrig' is some sort of miner malware

I tried using task manager and task scheduler to find and stop the 'xmrig' but I didnt find anything

I also tried looking inside the AppData\Roaming folder but didn't find anything

Please help me.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not a good place for generic computer issues. Anyway, try running an online antivirus from maybe [Trend Micro](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_fi/forHome/products/housecall.html) or [F-Secure](https://www.f-secure.com/en/online-scanner). For further help, try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Check Task Scheduler to see if there's a task that runs on login/startup. And RE: @vonPryz answer, try posting in serverfault.com, it's the more IT operations-oriented stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem using [Trend Micro](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_fi/forHome/products/housecall.html) Thanks to @vonPryz's. There was a malware exe file hidden in some folder and trend micro detected and deleted it!